# Jsf RichFaces a4j:support migration to a4j:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have problem with converting this code from **JSF 1.2** application to equivalent in **JSF 2.x** application

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="type" value="#{bean.type}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.typeList}"/>
    <a4j:support event="onchange"
                 ajaxSingle="false"
                 immediate="true"
                 reRender="myForm">
        <a4j:actionparam name="type" 
                         value="this.value" 
                         assignTo="#{bean.type}" 
                         noEscape="true"/>
    </a4j:support>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

How this code snippet works.

Depending on selected value in `#{bean.type}`, my page display different fields.
When User change `"type"` field the whole form is rerendered, but without form validation (`ajaxSingle="false", immediate="true", reRender="myForm"`).

I don't want to validate filds here, I just want to set new value to the `#{bean.type}` and rerender the page in order to show different fields (depending on `#{bean.type}`).
Thats why i need to manualy set `#{bean.type}` inside `a4j:actionparam`.

The nice feature about this code is that submited values in other fileds are preserved after rerendering.

I am trying to do the same thing in **JSF 2.x** with no success:

```
<h:selectOneMenu iid="type" value="#{bean.type}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.typeList}"/>
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="@form" execute="@this"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This:

```
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="@form" execute="@this"/>
```

will rerender whole form and I will lose submited values form other fields

This:

```
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="@form" execute="@form"/>
```

will submit, validate and rerender whole form (i want just submit without validation like in **JSF 1.2**)

This:

```
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="@form" execute="@form" immediate="true"/>
```

also does not work (work same as above)

So my question is how can I achive the same behavior in **JSF 2.x** ?

Thanks

Comment: Since you have fields in the form you don't want to be rerendered why are you rerendering the whole form in the first place?

Comment: Makhiel i want to rerender whole form to show different fields depending on selected value in type field . Some fileds are rendered always, and some only for special types (its very dynamic). And i want to preserve any values that user entered in any field that is still visible after rerendering.

Comment: Well, rerendering simply replaces the elements, so unless you save the values locally they will be lost. Wouldn't this be better solved entirely on the client side, hiding/showing the fields with JavaScript?

Comment: This works fine with JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.x. where a4j:support with ajaxSingle="false" immediate="true" submit whole form and sets submited values  in components (skiping validation and update model phase) so after rerendering values in other fields are not lost. I am simply looking for equivalent funcionality in JSF 2.x and RichFaces 4.x

Comment: Well, I've looked through the code but I don't see a way to skip the validation and update the values at the same time, unless you're up for updating the values yourself.

Comment: Hm, it's weird that your attempt with execute="@form" immediate="true" didn't work. immediate="true" should skip validation.

Comment: Andrey this works like you said for <a4j:support immediate="true"> in RichFaces 3.x. In RichFaces 4.x description of attribute 'immediate' for <a4j:ajax> tag is as follow:
"Flag indicating that, if this component is activated by the user, 
 notifications should be delivered to interested listeners and 
 actions immediately (that is, during Apply Request Values phase) rather than waiting until Invoke Application phase." 
So based on this description I believe that I can fire my listeners faster but it does not skip validation which is still invoked after listeners.

Comment: @bary After looking deeper - immediate="true" actually skips validation, but execute="@form" brings it back. Adding listener="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" to a4j:ajax may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andrey comment I found solution:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="type"
                 value="#{bean.type}"
                 valueChangeListener="#{bean.typeChangeListener}"
                 immediate="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.typeList}"/>
    <a4j:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" immediate="true"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and:

```
public void typeChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
  type = (String) event.getNewValue();
}
```

immediate on a4j:ajax causes that listener="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" is called during apply request values phase, and renderResponse skips validation.

immediate on h:selectOneMenu causes that valueChangeListener is also called during apply request values phase.

So I can submit whole form without validation, set type, rerender new fields based on changed type, and preserve submited values in other fileds.