# what can be the possible equivalent class for HtmlAjaxsupport in PrimeFaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, richfaces

a newbie to JSF here.I am exploring various JSF Frameworks like richfaces and primefaces and came across this HtmlAjaxsupport class in richfaces, but possibly not able to find its equivalent in primefaces.can anyone please provide any idea or insights?Any helplinks or samples to githubs would be highly Appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Richfaces is 'suset' ('dead') for a couple of years already. If you describe what the intention/usecase is of HtmlAjaxSupport maybe we can answer (I don't have the time to investigate ,yself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be `p:ajax` if I read what [`a4j:support`](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/a4j/support.html) does of which the `HtmlAjaxSupport` seems to be the java backing/component. But this a richfaces 3.x tag which has been superseded by (again already sunset) Richfaces 4 which has `a4j:ajax` [Jsf RichFaces a4j:support migration to a4j:ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218317/jsf-richfaces-a4jsupport-migration-to-a4jajax)